# How to test the callback for any actions in the controller using request.headers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, helper, response-headers, rswag

I have something like this controller:

```
class ApiApplicationController < ActionController::API
  
  before_action :record_information_from_headers

  private

  def record_information_from_headers
    InformationSet.create(info: request.headers['INFO'])
  end
end
```

All other controllers are inherited from `ApiApplicationController`

I want to test that my callback works before each method in child controllers. And try to use [Anonymous controller](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller)

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ApiApplicationController do
  controller(ApiApplicationController) do
    def index; end
  end

  let('INFO') { "some information" }

  it 'some' do
    get :index
    expect(InformationSet.last.info).to eq('some information')
  end
end
```

But, first of all, i have error:
"NoMethodError:
undefined method `controller' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApiApplicationController:Class"

And secondly, how do I pass the information to the header ?

I've already read [How to test ApplicationController method defined also as a helper method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739116/how-to-test-applicationcontroller-method-defined-also-as-a-helper-method) and [Rspec controller test for callback after_save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573403/rspec-controller-test-for-callback-after-save)

I would be grateful for any help)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the type: `describe ...Controller, type: :controller do`

The [Setting request headers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/5-1/docs/controller-specs/setting-request-headers) section of the docs shows how to set request headers for controller specs.

Comment: Thank you.I'll try it today. And may be you know something about the secondary question?

Comment: Umm, the second paragraph answers your second question.